# Why is it wrong to update UITableView's cells this way?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a download manager I have been struggling with updating the cells because of the "**reusable cells**"....

I had problems with updating the cells after a scroll but I found a workaround that doesn't work properly, this way is leading the app to crash after the cell becomes unvisible, I don't know why I hope you guys can explain, and if you know how to fix it please let me know.

I add a download task this way

```
func addDownloadTask(URL: NSURL) {

    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: mainQueue).downloadTaskWithURL(URL)

    let newDownload = RCHDownloadAddictModelClass(fileURL: URL)

    newDownload.downloadTask = session

    downloadingArray.append(newDownload)

    newDownload.downloadIndex = downloadingArray.indexOf(downloadingArray.last!)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    session.resume()

}
```

When a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` begins downloading this method get invoked

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    for (index, downloadModel) in downloadingArray.enumerate() {
        if downloadTask.isEqual(downloadModel.downloadTask) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
                /* xCode stops here when the app crashes */ let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell 
                let countOfBytesWritten: Double!
                if totalBytesExpectedToWrite < 0 {

                    countOfBytesWritten = 0

                } else {

                    countOfBytesWritten  = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

                }

                downloadModel.fileName = downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename
                downloadModel.downloadIndex = downloadingArray.indexOf(downloadModel)
                downloadModel.downloadSize = Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
                downloadModel.downloadProgress = Float(countOfBytesWritten)
                downloadModel.downloadTaskIdentifier = downloadTask.taskIdentifier
                downloadModel.didFinishDownload = false

                self.updateCell(cell, forRowAt: indexPath)

            })
        }
    }


}
```

and this is the way the cell gets updated:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("downloadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell

    updateCell(cell, forRowAt: indexPath)

    return cell
}



func updateCell(cell: RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let arrayInfo = downloadingArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellProgressView.setProgress((arrayInfo.downloadProgress)!, animated: true)
    cell.cellFileName.text = arrayInfo.fileName
    cell.cellDownloadSpeed.text = String(format: "%.1fMB", (arrayInfo.downloadSize / 1000000))
    cell.cellBlock = {

        switch arrayInfo.downloadTask.state {
        case .Running:
            arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
            cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case .Suspended:
            arrayInfo.downloadTask.resume()
            cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        default:
            arrayInfo.downloadTask.suspend()
            cell.cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "resume.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }

    if (arrayInfo.didFinishDownload == true) {
        cell.cellButton.hidden = true
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.text = "Finished."
        cell.cellProgressView.hidden = true
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.cellButton.hidden = false
        cell.cellProgressView.hidden = false
        cell.cellFinishIndicator.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see it at the apple doc :

```
public func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? 
// returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range

//cell will be nil when this row is not visible
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RCHDownloadAddictTableViewCell
```

then you call `self.updateCell(cell, forRowAt: indexPath)` it will crash

Comment: then how can I update it without calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` everytime ?

Comment: check the cell with tableview.visibleCells

Comment: just check the cell is nil or not is enough :-)

Comment: thanks mate, but when I try to check if it is nil, xCode tells me that my cell could never be nil, comparison is not allowed

Comment: check cell when you call  cellForRowAtIndexPath it returns UITableViewCell? then you can cancel it

Comment: I did that just before you said this! the issue has been fixed thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path with your code with one exception.

After your download has finished and you have stored the correct data into the array in the correct place you should run the code...

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Automatic)
```

This will then trigger the table to reload the cell at the correct index path. If that cell is on screen it will reload. If that cell is not on screen it will not reload. But the next time the cell is displayed it will now show the correct information.

In essence. Don't update the cell directly. Just tell the tableview that you have changed the data for that particular row.

Comment: I will add this!, I want a live feedback of the download mate that is why I am updating directly. thanks :)

Comment: @Raffi you can definitely use this to update the cell's progress. But do it via the tableview. As WilsonXJ pointed out. You don't know that the row is still on screen and if not then the `cell` you are referring to will be on screen displaying data from a different row. So you might update a label to say "David" when that cell is now on the row for "Sarah". (for example).

Comment: I understand your example now, but I don't understand how to update the cells via tableview can you be more clear please ?

Comment: @Raffi OK. First thing to think is that the cells are not there. So if you're putting anything directly into a cell it needs to go into an array instead. So if you want to show the progress of a download then create an array and in that array store the download progress. Then just run the code in my answer and when updating the cell use the values from that array. It looks like you're doing something similar to that already with the `downloadModel` or something?

Comment: If I have an array that stores the progress already why do I need another array ?

Comment: @Raffi you don't need two. I'm just saying. You'll need an array. If you have an array already then use that one.

Comment: I tried using it the tableView is updating in a weird visible way :/, Can I turn this discussion to a chat ?

Comment: @Raffi sure go ahead.

Comment: I am unable to do that because of low reputation, I am still new to the website

Comment: @Raffi ah. Well I'll have to come back tomorrow as I'm not on my computer now. Try changing the animation type to `.None` if it looks like the cells are fading in and out.